# How can I make Emacs org docs more beautiful in github repository?

Tags: emacs, github, markdown, markup, org-mode

github supports several markup languages, one of which is `Emacs org mode` docs.

1. But it always look ugly with the default CSS file(much better than
   the default one in built-in org mode, though.
2. Also it seems that the
   *source code block* does not have syntax highlight either.

So is it possible to make it more beautiful with some minor changes in org files? Or can you give me some advice or good practice?

Comment: Recent org-mode has added export to markdown, you might want to give it a try.

Comment: @rvf0068 which version? Have you got a try and how do you feel like it?

Comment: See for example https://github.com/rvf0068/org-document-test, the file README.md was exported from first.org. This was using the development version of org, (from git).

Comment: @rvf0068 Yeah, it's better. But not as good as I have imagined though.

Comment: There is a bug report for the source code block issue: https://github.com/github/markup/issues/186  No activity yet, though.

Answer (score 6):

Github uses [org-ruby](https://github.com/bdewey/org-ruby) to convert org-mode to html. It appears that recent versions of org-ruby support both lower case org-mode keywords and syntax highlighting in the source code blocks (among other nice things). Until it is upgraded in the official Github, it looks like the only options are either to use upper case BEGIN_SRC/END_SRC or export your org files to html/md in emacs with any options/css/etc you like and post the resulting files on Github.

Answer (score 1):

Githubs Org-Mode support is upgraded *but #+TITLE*: is unsupported, like links that are mostly bugged. So it works mostly.